# My system isn’t bootable, how can I do a kernel update?

Tags: boot, live-usb, amdgpu

My system isn’t bootable because the hardware in my laptop is unsupported by the linux kernel I’m using. Is there a way I am able to boot into a live USB on my laptop, update the kernel on my laptop and boot back again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing with a different kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94156/installing-with-a-different-kernel)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616529/update-system-from-live-session seems to answer this but you might need to tweak some of the commands.  Mind that it is easier to create a live session on another computer and reinstall. If needed you can backup the personal files from a live session prior to installing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start from a live USB stick, mount the broken installation, chroot into the broken system and install a working kernel. During the chroot phase you are essentially using the kernel of the Live system while working with the operating system files (`/`) of the installed system.

Tutorial for the mounting and chroot part: https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Installing the new kernel version will automatically update grub so the new kernel is available during boot, you should only check that /boot contains the expected kernel images while you chroot and after you installed the new kernel.